# Build a dictionary from a list with a structured pattern

Tags: python, list, dictionary, converters

How can I get a dictionary like below from this text file:

```
[Fri Aug 20]
shamooshak 4-0 milan
Tehran 2-0 Ams
Liverpool 0-2 Mes
[Fri Aug 19]
Esteghlal 1-0 perspolise
Paris 2-0 perspolise
[Fri Aug 20]
RahAhan 0-0 milan
[Wed Agu 11]
Munich 3-3 ABC
[Wed Agu 12]
RM 0-0 Tarakto
[Sat Jau 01]
Bayern 2-0 Manchester
```

I have tried list comprehension, for loops with enumerate function. But I could not build this list.

My desired dictionary is:
`{'[Fri Aug 20]':[shamooshak 4-0 milan, Tehran 2-0 Ams,Liverpool 0-2 Mes],'[Fri Aug 19]':[Esteghlal 1-0 perspolise,Paris 2-0 perspolise]`... and so on.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it will include valid Python data-structures

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is lines of text...

```
def process_arbitrary_text(text):
    obj = {}
    arr = []
    k = None
    for line in text:
        if line[0] == '[' and line[-1] == ']':
            if k and arr: # omit empty keys?
                obj[k] = arr
            k = line
            arr = []
        else:
            arr.append(line)
    return obj

desired_dict = process_arbitrary_text(text)
```

Edit: since you edited to say it was a text file, just include the following pattern

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        # do something...or:
    text = file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions (`re` module) and your sample text:

```
text = '''[Fri Aug 20]
shamooshak 4-0 milan
Tehran 2-0 Ams
Liverpool 0-2 Mes
[Fri Aug 19]
Esteghlal 1-0 perspolise
Paris 2-0 perspolise
[Fri Aug 20]
RahAhan 0-0 milan
[Wed Agu 11]
Munich 3-3 ABC
[Wed Agu 12]
RM 0-0 Tarakto
[Sat Jau 01]
Bayern 2-0 Manchester'''
x = re.findall('\[.+?\][^\[]*',text)
x = [i.split('\n') for i in x]
d = dict()
for i in x:
    d[i[0]] = [j for j in i[1:] if j!='']
```

It gives following dictionary `d`:

```
`{'[Fri Aug 20]': ['RahAhan 0-0 milan'], '[Sat Jau 01]': ['Bayern 2-0 Manchester'], '[Fri Aug 19]': ['Esteghlal 1-0 perspolise', 'Paris 2-0 perspolise'], '[Wed Agu 12]': ['RM 0-0 Tarakto'], '[Wed Agu 11]': ['Munich 3-3 ABC']}`
```

I overlooked that dates might repeat, as pointed by mad_, to avoid losing data replace `for` loop with

```
for i in x:
    d[i[0]] = []
for i in x:
    d[i[0]] = d[i[0]]+[j for j in i[1:] if j!='']
```

Comment: You do realize the data for key `[Fri Aug 20]` does not match as you are updating the key with the new value rather then appending

Answer (score 0):

A `for` can be a savior here

```
a='''[Fri Aug 20]
shamooshak 4-0 milan
Tehran 2-0 Ams
Liverpool 0-2 Mes
[Fri Aug 19]
Esteghlal 1-0 perspolise
Paris 2-0 perspolise
[Fri Aug 20]
RahAhan 0-0 milan
[Wed Agu 11]
Munich 3-3 ABC
[Wed Agu 12]
RM 0-0 Tarakto
[Sat Jau 01]
Bayern 2-0 Manchester'''
d={}
temp_value=[]
temp_key=''
for i in a.split('\n'):

    if i.startswith('['):
        if temp_key and temp_key in d:
            d[temp_key]=d[temp_key]+temp_value
        elif temp_key:
            d[temp_key]=temp_value

        temp_key=i
        temp_value=[]

    else:
        temp_value.append(i)

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'[Fri Aug 20]': ['shamooshak 4-0 milan', 'Tehran 2-0 Ams', 'Liverpool 0-2 Mes', 'RahAhan 0-0 milan'], '[Fri Aug 19]': ['Esteghlal 1-0 perspolise', 'Paris 2-0 perspolise'], '[Wed Agu 12]': ['RM 0-0 Tarakto'], '[Wed Agu 11]': ['Munich 3-3 ABC']}
```